# How do I remove duplicates rows in my MySQL database? (Keep the one with lowest Primary ID)

Tags: sql, mysql, database, unique

Let's say I want to first select rows which have download_link the same.  Then, I want to keep the one that has lowest primary id, and throw away the rest.

Is there an easy SQL statement for this? Would this work?

```
delete from mytable
where id not in
    (select min(id)
     from mytable
     group by download_link);
```

Comment: Looks like it should work, do you have any specific reason for not simply trying it?

Comment: It says this: ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'mytable' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need temporary tables or subqueries. You can do it with a simple join:

```
DELETE t0
FROM mytable AS t0
JOIN mytable AS t1 ON t1.download_link=t0.download_link AND t1.id<t0.id;
```

That is, “delete every row for which there is another row with the same link and a lower ID”.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work:

```
DELETE FROM `table` 
WHERE `id` NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(`id`) 
    FROM `table`
    GROUP BY `download_link`)
```

Just to be on the safe side, before running the actual delete query, you might want to do an equivalent select to see what gets deleted:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE `id` NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(`id`) 
    FROM `table`
    GROUP BY `download_link`)
```

Comment: It says this: ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'mytable' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Ah, right, I remember getting that error too. Solved it using a temporary table: CREATE TABLE #tmp (id int); INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT MIN(id) FROM `table` GROUP BY `download_link`; DELETE FROM `table` WHERE NOT `id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM #tmp); DROP TABLE #tmp;

Answer (score 1):

Error 1093 prevents your approach working in MySQL.  Work-around by creating a temporary table:

```
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table_purge SELECT MIN(id) id FROM table GROUP BY download_link;
  DELETE FROM table where id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table_purge);
```

Edited to add an alternative work-around that doesn't involve an explicit temporary table.  Presumably this works because the query execution plan naturally creates a temporary table anyway:

```
 DELETE table
  FROM table 
  NATURAL JOIN (
      SELECT id, download_link
      FROM table
      NATURAL JOIN (
          SELECT MIN(id) min_id, download_link
          FROM table
          GROUP BY download_link ) table_min
      WHERE id > min_id
  )  table_to_purge;
```

Answer (score 0):

try following query

```
 delete from table where id not in 
 (select * from 
      (select min(id) from table group by download_link)
 SWA_TABAL)
```

It works fine with mysql 5.0.x